# I want to output the permission a user account doesn't have

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the query to output the permission user has.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [APP_Computer_User_Id], 
    [APP_Role_Name], 
    [APP_Permission_Name]
FROM [ADMINS].[APP_USER] U 
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_USER_ROLE] UR ON U.[APP_User_Id]=UR.[APP_User_Id]
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE] URO ON UR.[APP_Role_ID]=URO.[APP_Role_ID]
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE_PERMISSION] RP ON RP.[APP_Role_ID]=UR.[APP_Role_ID]
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_PERMISSION] P ON RP.[APP_Permission_Id]=P.[APP_Permission_Id]
```

I've tried left outer join, subqueries, and several other steps but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the users and permission values by using a cross join.  Then you can use `left join` (or `not exists` or `not in`) to filter out the ones that are already there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [APP_Computer_User_Id], [APP_Permission_Name]
FROM [ADMINS].[APP_USER] U CROSS JOIN
     [ADMINS].[APP_PERMISSION] P LEFT JOIN
     [ADMINS].[APP_USER_ROLE] UR 
     ON U.[APP_User_Id] = UR.[APP_User_Id] LEFT JOIN
     [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE] URO
     ON UR.[APP_Role_ID] = URO.[APP_Role_ID] LEFT JOIN
     [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE_PERMISSION] RP
     ON RP.[APP_Role_ID] = UR.[APP_Role_ID] AND
        RP.[APP_Permission_Id] = P.[APP_Permission_Id]
WHERE P.[APP_Permission_Id] IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
appUser.[APP_Computer_User_Id]
[APP_Role_Name], 
[APP_Permission_Name] 
 from  [ADMINS].[APP_USER] appUser, [ADMINS].[APP_USER_ROLE] UR

JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE] URO ON UR.[APP_Role_ID]=URO.[APP_Role_ID]
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE_PERMISSION] RP ON RP.[APP_Role_ID]=UR.    [APP_Role_ID]
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_PERMISSION] P ON RP.[APP_Permission_Id]=P.   [APP_Permission_Id]
Left join  (select  [APP_User_Id] from  [ADMINS].[APP_USER] uu where  p.  [APP_User_Id] = uu.[APP_User_Id])  U ON U.[APP_User_Id]=UR.[APP_User_Id] 

where U.[APP_User_Id] is null
```